# Export web page as static standalone html file

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs

I would like to have a recurring job that browses to a URL, and exports it as static, standalone HTML. By standalone I mean that all images be made into inline data, so that everything can stand in a single HTML file.

The goal is to then use that HTML file as content of an email.

I am thinking of using phantomjs to do that. I could use the pdf or image export, but it is not really good for email, because it doesn't resize with viewport size. I found how to get `page.content` but it seems to produce the source, with references to images instead of inlined images.

Is there a tool somewhere, or a usage of phantomjs, that would allow me to do that ?

Comment: `it seems to produce the source` Correct. And then you have to get images and resources yourself, convert them to base64 (since you want inline data) and rewrite links in html. But your know that already, so what is your question?

Comment: My question is "is there a tool that does that", because as you can imagine, doing that isn't a one line work